# Changing architecture while upgrading (ubuntu 16lts)?

Tags: upgrade, architecture

I wonder if there is a way to change architecture (from 32 to 64bits), even upgrading (or not) from 16.04lts to 18.04lts ?
I've looked at do-release-upgrade and other options, but I saw nothing about architecture.
Is it at least possible ?

Rm *

Comment: I guess you are looking for this https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation

Comment: Yes,
lateafter I found this post too. A really long answer, not so old in fact (2018 ?) for the last comment. 
So I won't try, as recommended, I'll be able to use a dualboot instead.

Thanks '